# Get my domain-joined work computer to work in my home network

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-shares, home-networking

In my home network I have a wireless router to which you can connect two USB drives. I use these disks much like a simple NAS.

The problem is that my work computer that is connected to a Domain on the job can not see the router, even if it connects wirelessly to the Internet. My work computer can not see any computer on the network. But all the other computers can see the work computer.
How should I configure my domain-joined work computer so that I can access the other computers in my home network?

**Computers on the network:**

- Work Computer: Windows 7
- PC 1: Windows 7
- PC 2: Windows Xp
- iPad 1

Comment: When you say "cannot see" what are you doing to try and see the drives or other computers?  What happens if you put `\\<router ip address\` into explorer on Windows?  (eg \\192.168.1.1\ )

Comment: If I look under the network on my computer, I can only see your own computer. And if I try typing \\ip-number I just get error message after a while that the address can not be found.
And if I try to ping they get no contact. Not in any direction. And my work computer can not ping the router with USB drives that it is connected to

Comment: Is your work machine running any sort of personal firewall?  McAfee HIPS for example?

Comment: It is using Symantic Endpoint Protection, but it is the same problem if I disable it

Comment: Focus on ping - can you ping if both SEP and Windows firewall are disabled?

Comment: I have disable both SEP and Windows firewall and the ping in both directions timed out

Comment: If the machine is definitely connected to the network and has an IP address in the same subnet as the other devices, then there must be something else blocking ping.  Can you surf if SEP is disabled?